# Cartesian product of simplices e.g. stochastic matrices

Tags: geometry

Each row in a (row-)stochastic matrix is a discrete probability distribution, and as such lives on a simplex. The space of stochastic matrices is the Cartesian product of these simplices. Is there another description for this space?

For example, a $2\times2$ stochastic matrix could be parameterized as
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    a & 1-a\\
    b & 1-b\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

with $a,b \in [0,1]$. To me, that space looks like a unit square. Each point on the unit square is associated with a point $(a,b)$ which can then be associated with a stochastic matrix.

There's another possible shape I can identify with the space, which is a 3-simplex with 4 points:

$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0\\
    1 & 0\\
    \end{bmatrix}, 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    1 & 0\\
    \end{bmatrix},
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0\\
    0 & 1\\
    \end{bmatrix},
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    0 & 1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$

Any convex combination of those four points produces a valid stochastic matrix. However, there are distinct convex combinations that produce the same matrix. So while I think I can squint and interpret the space unit square as a simplex (by adding the two diagonals and "raising" one diagonal off the plane), it doesn't seem like the most appropriate characterization.

Is there a special word for "Cartesian product of simplices"? 
By the way, here's what I think is a depiction of the Cartesian product of two 2-simplices

[image]

Comment: Have you figured this out by any chance?

Comment: No, I didn't find a suitable name.